# KendoUI Grid - rollback from from a remove row

Tags: kendo-ui

I am creating a custom transport for KendoUI that would connect Kendo to a number of cool data sources like webSQL. My Kendo Grid problem is that when I implement the delete/destroy command I am not able to prevent the grid from the actual remove row to happen, even if the data source layer has responded with an error.

I get called via the `RemoteTransport.destroy` method. The input parameter contains an error and a success callback, but even if I call the error callback, or try to return a "false", or try to return a $.Deferred that I eventually reject: the grid row is gone. Actually it's gone before I get called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you would want the **cancelChanges** method on the grid.

http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#cancelchanges

*A response from the KendoUI forum helps decoupling the UI part from the data layer part*

> In the RemoteTransport 
>   call the rejection handler this will cause an exception in the
>   DataSource. In the DataSource definition place an error handler that
>   call the actual cancelChanges or whatever rollback method the control
>   will have. Still inperfect - but at least doable.

Comment: Thank you, but not exactly. My code is a RemoteTransport and has absolutely no knowledge of grids or other kind of UI components - it's just a data layer. So I can not talk directly with the client control.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it still seems like you should be able to call "cancelChanges" on the grid. The grid has knowledge of the datasource right?  You know when the call failed.  You can't get a reference to the grid and call "cancelChanges"?

Comment: I got a response from the KendoUI forum as well, that helps decoupling the UI part from the data layer part. In the RemoteTransport I  have to call the rejection handler that will cause an exception in the DataSource. In the data source I should place an error handler the does the actual cancelChanges or whatever rollback method the control will have. Still inperfect - but at least doable.